# SQL Syntax error on his computer, but not on mine?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, syntax

I'm developing an application that executes queries from time to time to retrieve data from my MySQL database. I recently asked a friend to try it out in order to check if it works properly ... which it apparently doesn't. It started with his applcation to stop responding directly after startup. I figured we had to debug it somehow so I wrapped the Main() method in Program.cs within a try..catch statement. That returned the error ""You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"". Now I've narrowed this error down to two possible queries. here they are:

Query 1:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + newsTable + " ;"
```

newsTable contains: news

Query 2:

```
"SELECT " + newsTitle + ", " + newsAuth + " FROM " + newsTable + " ORDER BY " + newsID + " DESC LIMIT " + countnews + ", " + countnews + 1 + ";"
```

They all contain strings except the countnews variable contains an integer.

The weird thing about all this is that this error never occurs when I launch the application on my computer, but works just fine. He just updated MySQL and we're on the same .NET framework, 4.

I'm out of ideas!

Thanks in advance,

Fredrik

PS: Worth noting might be that both these queries are located in the Main() method in my form application. Of course it's placed AFTER InitializeComponent();

Comment: Is the schema for the databases the same on each machine? Also, do you have the exact error coming from MySQL on your coworker's machine?

Comment: You need to narrow it down further by seeing the offending query. Your column and table names seem to be dynamic (where are they defined?) and it's probable that the error is in those names.

Comment: "narrowed it to two possible queries" - all you need to do is handle the Exception correctly and you'll have everything: stack trace, line number, error text, etc. The most I portent thing to look at is: what was the exact query you tried to execute. Since you are building it at runtime, we can't tell you that..

Comment: The database structure is exacty the same in both of our computers. As are the values, i exported everythig as a .sql. And infact, this is the full error. Could you please elaborate how to make it display more information. That would indeed make all this alot easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to understand :
-make two stored procedures for your 2 queries not sql injection
why?
because:
-stored procedure is easy to test on MySql Database and if it works, it works everywhere
-it is a bad id to try debugging with c#  sql, it is fastidious like your post show it
;-)

Comment: Well I see your point. But the values passed in these queries are the exact same on my comp, since I exported the entire .sql.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so I went through everything again and realized that the lacking human factor strikes again. I forgot to export the actual DATA aswell with the .sql, which was truly retarded of me, it was 03:00 am .. Thanks for trying to help me solving this silly issue, truly appreciate it.

Fredrik